# Does onBroadcastReceiver work in the background?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an auto reply sms application. The function is that when a sms is coming, the application auto reply a busy message to the sender. 
I also create a activity. In this activity I have a broadcastReceiver method, when a sms is coming, this method uses MessageManager to send an outcome sms. But it seems like this application can not work when it is in the background. What do I have to do.

Here is the code I used:

```
public class AutoReplySMSliteActivity extends Activity {

    //-----------------------------------------------------RECEIVER LISTENER----------------------------------------------
    //Create auto- reply
    private void sendSMS(String cellNo, String msg)
    {
        SmsManager sender = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sender.sendTextMessage(cellNo, null, msg, null, null);
    }

    //Setup sender number which is got from receiver
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    };

    //-------------------------------------------------------onCreate METHOD-----------------------------------------------------------
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //Setup broadcast receiver
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);




}
```

in androidmanifest, I have a receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And that is my Receiver class:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Get the sender phone number and bind to string str
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        Log.i("SMSReceiver", "Sender number receives: " + str);

        //Send broadcast str to ListReceiver to compare
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        Log.i("SMSReceiver", "Broadcast data....");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call Service when the message comes. You should move all the functionality to Service . So it also runs in the background .

Comment: it is a le to use view in services

Comment: Services run in the "background" but still on the app's UI thread. To truly run a process in the background, you should use an IntentService or if that is not an option, a Runnable.